# Why the need to explicitly delete dynamically allocated memory?

Tags: c++, c, operating-system, new-operator, delete-operator

Why do we need to explicitly delete dynamically allocated memory, when the OS itself takes back memory of process? In the kind of situation where dynamic memory is allocated inside a constructor, why do we need to delete it in the destructor?

Comment: The OS only cleans up after your process dies. If you're writing something that is supposed to run "forever", either you need to make sure you manage your memory, or buy a machine with inifinite memory.

Comment: Because it's a good habit to be tidy, and if the program continually allocates and releases memory, you will have to.

Comment: Or you can be like the Chrome browser and keep allocating memory until the system freezes.

Comment: Because someday a wanna-be programmer will realize that it's more than a simple hello world they are taught in their lessons has to be made.

Comment: Does anybody know if common `malloc` implementations return memory to the operating system when they can? One issue that has not been mentioned in the answers so far is the possibility that, while a process does not run out of virtual address space itself, it does needlessly consume swap space from memory that was allocated, used, and never freed. If the `malloc` implementation releases memory back to the operand system when it is freed and whole pages become available for that, it could avoid that.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil: A typical implementation is the following: `malloc` tries to allocate memory from the heap. If there is enough unused adjacent memory on the heap, `malloc` uses this memory. If there is not enough unused adjacent memory on the heap, `malloc` requests new pages from the operating system and uses them. When memory is freed, `free` typically tells the operating system which pages are not longer needed. The operating system can then reclaim these pages.

Comment: @Xaver: Source?

Comment: @Eric Postpischil: Take a look at the source code of `glibc`'s memory functions, for example at https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/malloc/malloc.c.html#3092 . In the implementation of `__libc_free` you can see that a test is performed to determine if a memory fragment is mapped to virtual memory (line 3111).

Comment: @Xaver: That test doesn't do what you claim it does.  It releases pages allocated by `mmap` back to the OS when they are later freed.  It does not release pages allocated by `malloc` (because the heap ran out of space), even when they theoretically become no longer needed.

Answer (score 5):

To some extent, you do not *have* to explicitly delete allocated memory. You *can* let memory leaks accumulate until your program ends and the OS reclaims the memory for you. A better question is do you *want* to?

The OS will not reclaim the memory until your process ends. Can you afford to wait that long? If you allocate less than a megabyte of memory over the course of your program, you are likely to not see bad side-effects. However, if your program could be run for hours, or even days, how much memory is then leaked? Eventually you get to the point where other programs are slowed down because your program is hogging all the memory – and it's not even using that memory; the leaked memory is floating around unused and unusable.

If you learn to clean up after yourself while your programs are small, you'll be prepared to tackle larger projects that can potentially leak all available memory on a system. Also, it's polite to not take more than what you need (or what you've reasonably estimated as needed) of a limited resource.

Comment: I like the phrasing; it is polite to not take more than needed :)

Answer (score 1):

> why we need to explicitly delete dynamically allocated memory, when OS itself takes back memory of process

Because we might want the process to keep running. If you allocate a megabyte every second and don't deallocate any memory, then after a day of running the process, you've allocated 84 gigabytes. At some point you will run out of memory. It would be highly inconvenient if we had to restart all programs every few hours just to give operating system some memory back.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the OS will clean-up after you, but there are 2 major problems:

1. Destructors of leaked objects will not be called.
2. Your program can run out of memory (and other resources it leaks) WHILE it's running.

Having said that, you can use smart pointers and STL containers to manage memory and froget about it.

Comment: I don't agree that you can forget about it if you use smart pointers and STL containers. In some cases, automatic clean-up will not happen. For example, if you have cyclic references.

Comment: @Xaver you cannot have a cyclic reference with `unique_ptr` or STL containers. These are the main tools you should be using anyway. In the rare cases you do need a `shared_ptr`, you should use it with `weak_ptr` to avoid cyclic dependencies.

Comment: @Xaver of course, the whole of the C++ community cannot "forget about memory management" as direct memory management is one of the reasons why C++ is used in the first place. I was referring to OP as someone who's apparently new to memory management.

Answer (score 0):

The OS recycle of memory will only happen after/during the termination of the program.

If you are writing a program that persists for a long time, such as a background daemon running as long as the PC is on, due to unfreed memory created during the operation, your PC's memory resource will eventually get used up, triggering the Low Memory Killer of your OS, which kills some programs (which may include yours) and triggers the recycling until the system has enough memory again. From a stability perspective you want to avoid this as much as possible.